# Improve page load performance with Google ads

Tags: google-adsense

I'm starting a new development of a site and checking constantly with GTMetrix the Page load & YSlow.

All was almost perfect 'till I placed a Google ad from AdSense.

This is the report just before I placed the script:

[image]

and after I place the script (only one):

[image]

As can be seen, the performance fall down drastically. The number of request is big.

Is there any way I can do to improve this?

By the way, the script is placed just before thw  tag with the following:

```
<script async src="//pagead2.googlesyndication.com/pagead/js/adsbygoogle.js" defer="defer"></script>
<script defer="defer">
(adsbygoogle = window.adsbygoogle || []).push({});
</script>
```

Comment: I don't see how Google ads is 29 requests. Whats the URL?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sad truth is that google adsense is an advertising service. They rent a window of your webpage for advertisements. These advertisements can contain any number of requests to other third party helper URLs and may even contain unoptimized content. The content is what the advertisers produce, and you really have no control over it.

All I can suggest if you really want to improve (a.k.a. speed up) loading time is to disable all the fancy offerings with google ads such as animated ads, video ads, ads that expand, etc. Just stick with the basic text, and basic graphic ads, and if that isn't fast enough, then disable everything but text-based ads.

Now, having said all that, taking my advice MIGHT cost you money, and I say this because people are visual creatures. They like to see videos and graphics and advertisers understand this. If you remove graphical/animated based ads, then people will look for other graphics and there may be fewer advertisers bidding on your ad slots which can result in less revenue for you.

Comment: Even disabling types of ads won't change this report.   Google AdSense doesn't use cache headers on it script snippet that tools like this are asking for.  If you want to use AdSense, you just have to accept lower scores on these tools.

Comment: Yes, we will have to accept it!!!